# Export graph with fusion chart python or php

Tags: export, fusioncharts

I have an application in Django with Fusion Chart.

I need to export jquery graphs, using actually http://export.api3.fusioncharts.com, but I'm using HTTPS, and fusionchart doesn't support https.

Any solution for my problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: Try setting "html5exporthandler" attribute in the chart element as https://export.api3.fusioncharts.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup `FusionCharts PHP Export handler` on your own server. Follow this [article](http://kb.fusioncharts.com/questions/288/How+is+the+Server+side+export+output+returned+as+Download?).

UPDATE: Now FusionChart Export Handler is available in HTTPS. Use https://export.api3.fusioncharts.com/. I hope this solves it.

Comment: I would use another solution without installing PHP.